# How do I remove folder path in URL to display something like myWebsite.com/addmissionlist.aspx instead of myWebsite.com/admission/addmissionlist.aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have some pages in admission folder, some pages in report folder. How do I remove or hide the folder path in URL to display something like?

www.myWebsite.com/addmissionlist.aspx rather than www.myWebsite.com/admission/addmissionlist.aspx   and

www.myWebsite.com/paymentlist.aspx rather than www.myWebsite.com/report/paymentlist.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to move the file up one folder in the directory. You will not be able to 'hide' a folder, but would need to move the `addmissionlist.aspx` file to the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use url rewrite https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

on your case. you need to add routes in a method that is called from the handler for the Application_Start event in the Global.asax file. it will be

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "addmissionlist.aspx",
        "~/admission/addmissionlist.aspx");
}
```